# New code in Grails generated controller

Tags: grails, grails-controller

Since I have upgraded my Grails version the generated code in controller's save method has changed.  I have gone through the documentation which explains each item separately but it would be great if someone can explain the `request.withFormat` part holistically.

The following snippet is taken from an automatically generated `Save` action. One thing that is puzzling me is. Which line here indicates, render "show" view after successful save operation?

```
def save(User userInstance) {
    if (userInstance == null) {
        notFound()
        return
    }

    if (userInstance.hasErrors()) {
        respond userInstance.errors, view:'create'
        return
    }

    userInstance.save flush:true

    request.withFormat {
        form multipartForm {
            flash.message = message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [
                message(code: 'user.label', default: 'User'),
                userInstance.id
            ])
            redirect userInstance
        }
        '*' { respond userInstance, [status: CREATED] }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`request.withFOrmat` can be used to return different response types depending on the request accept header.

The example from the [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/withFormat.html):

```
request.withFormat {
    html bookList:books // render html
    js { render "alert('hello')" } // render javascript
    xml { render books as XML } // render xml
}
```

In your example the controller can return two types of responses. One for multipart form requests and one that is used for all other requests:

```
request.withFormat {
    form multipartForm {
        // if it is a multipart form request -> add a flash message and redirect to another action
        flash.message = message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [
            message(code: 'user.label', default: 'User'),
            userInstance.id
        ])
        redirect userInstance
    }
    '*' { 
         // for all other request types, respond with the `userInstance` object
         respond userInstance, [status: CREATED] 
    }
}
```

Comment: But after executing this code my controller redirects to "SHOW" view. Where is that indicated?

Comment: "redirect userInstance" does the redirect to the show action - but i can't figure out where in the http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/redirect.html you will find this variant

Comment: Still how does `redirect userInstance` redirect to show view? Nowhere it is mentioned which view to redirect to!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this is an undocumented behavior of redirect. But looking at grails code we can figure out that it uses this convention: 
 
If redirect takes just a PERSISTED object as argument, it will infer the show action url and use the object id as the url argument. 
 
There is a Jira for that doc issue at https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-11862

 
 Some more resources on that:
http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/New-controller-syntax-explained-td4654914.html

 
Regarding the withFormat snippet, it embraces three situations:
1) "form" A simple form submission excpecting an html response (enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
2) "multipartForm" A file upload form submission excpecting an html response (enctype="multipart/form-data")
3) "*" All other options, like json or xml in restfull requests

Situations 1 and 2 are handled by the same code.